# pandas daylight shifting values

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I look for drop/add the hour which correspond to a daylight. I process as follow but I obtain only shift on datetime since also want a shift for values.

Anyone has a solution for that ?

```
df  = pd.DataFrame({'value' : range(10)}, index=pd.date_range(pd.datetime(2014,3,30, 0,  0), freq='H', periods=10))
df  = df.tz_localize(pytz.timezone('UCT'))

dfP = df.tz_convert(pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris'))

>>> df
                           value
2014-03-30 00:00:00+00:00      a
2014-03-30 01:00:00+00:00      b
2014-03-30 02:00:00+00:00      c
2014-03-30 03:00:00+00:00      d
2014-03-30 04:00:00+00:00      e
2014-03-30 05:00:00+00:00      f
2014-03-30 06:00:00+00:00      g
2014-03-30 07:00:00+00:00      h
2014-03-30 08:00:00+00:00      i
2014-03-30 09:00:00+00:00      j

[10 rows x 1 columns]
>>> dfP
                           value
2014-03-30 01:00:00+01:00      a
2014-03-30 03:00:00+02:00      b
2014-03-30 04:00:00+02:00      c
2014-03-30 05:00:00+02:00      d
2014-03-30 06:00:00+02:00      e
2014-03-30 07:00:00+02:00      f
2014-03-30 08:00:00+02:00      g
2014-03-30 09:00:00+02:00      h
2014-03-30 10:00:00+02:00      i
2014-03-30 11:00:00+02:00      j

[10 rows x 1 columns]
```

I want dfP is : (instead of above)

```
>>> dfP
                           value
2014-03-30 01:00:00+01:00      a
2014-03-30 03:00:00+02:00      c
2014-03-30 04:00:00+02:00      d
2014-03-30 05:00:00+02:00      e
2014-03-30 06:00:00+02:00      f
2014-03-30 07:00:00+02:00      g
2014-03-30 08:00:00+02:00      h
2014-03-30 09:00:00+02:00      i
2014-03-30 10:00:00+02:00      j
2014-03-30 11:00:00+02:00      Nan
```

where a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j can be any value.

Comment: You can drop the timezone and subtract the first index. But what is the meaning of `value`?

Comment: If the daily peak of your power consumption is at 19h in summer time it's the same in winter time. There is no shift ! I don't understand your method ? :s

Answer (score 0):

Here in value2, the result I need.

```
    value   value2
2014-01-01 00:00:00+01:00   0   0
…       
2014-03-29 22:00:00+01:00   2110    2110
2014-03-29 23:00:00+01:00   2111    2111
2014-03-30 00:00:00+01:00   2112    2112
2014-03-30 01:00:00+01:00   2113    2113
2014-03-30 03:00:00+02:00   2114    2115
2014-03-30 04:00:00+02:00   2115    2116   <- shift + 1
…       
2014-10-25 19:00:00+02:00   7146    7147
2014-10-25 20:00:00+02:00   7147    7148
2014-10-25 21:00:00+02:00   7148    7149
2014-10-25 22:00:00+02:00   7149    7150
2014-10-25 23:00:00+02:00   7150    7151
2014-10-26 00:00:00+02:00   7151    7152
2014-10-26 01:00:00+02:00   7152    7153
2014-10-26 02:00:00+02:00   7153    7154
2014-10-26 02:00:00+01:00   7154    7154   <- shift - 1
2014-10-26 03:00:00+01:00   7155    7155
2014-10-26 04:00:00+01:00   7156    7156
```

Whith the following code :
    i = 8730
    start = pd.datetime(2014,1,1, 0, 0)
    df  = pd.DataFrame({'value' : range(i)}, index=pd.date_range(start, freq='H', periods=i))
    df = df.tz_localize('Etc/GMT-1')
    dfParis = df.tz_convert(pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris'))

Values here 1 to 8730 must be considered as other in true life.

Has someone a solution ?